# Прописная обязательна во втором слове названия?

Tags: орфография

> «Центральный Детский магазин на Лубянке»

Нужны ли кавычки, если так и пишется, без ООО или ТОО, АОО и т. д.

*Детский* - со строчной?

Если *Центральный* не писать для краткости, тогда Детский обязательно с прописной?

Answer (score 3):

Вообще говоря, самое правильное название для этого магазина - это Центральный детский магазин на Лубянке.

http://www.the-village.ru/village/city/picture-story/173031-detskiy-mir-na-lubyanke

С прописной буквы пишется первое слово, слова "детский, магазин" имеют реальное, а не условное значение и поэтому должны писаться со строчной буквы.

Иногда в подобных случаях (после слова "Центральный") второе слово пишется с прописной, если будет закреплено второе название - "Детский магазин на Лубянке". Тогда "Детский" надо писать с прописной.

А пока каждый пишет по своему разумению.